# Publish build artifacts step fails, when using fileshare (TFS 2015)

Tags: node.js, build, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, tfs-2015

TFS Version: 14.102.25423.0 (Tfs2015.Update3)

In my build definition when I set the **Path** argument of the

> Publish Build Artifacts step

with

> Artifact type: **File share**

to

> \VSALM\share

Behind the scene this build step executes a node.js script function which is called recursively, but there is a bug and the function repeats itself over and over again while trying to create the drop folder**.
The failing node.js script is

> mkdir.js

and resides below the build agent folder:

> agent\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.28\node_modules\shelljs\src\mkdir.js

Name of the failing function is:

> mkdirSyncRecursive

The error msg:

> 016-07-23T21:22:02.3703397Z shell.js: internal error
>   2016-07-23T21:22:02.3703397Z RangeError: Maximum call stack size
>   exceeded

--> Stackoverflow
When I enter an absolut path like

> c:\workspaces\share

I get this error:

> 2016-07-23T21:03:07.5727256Z shell.js: internal error
>   2016-07-23T21:03:07.5727256Z Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir
>   'C:\workspaces\share'

### Workaround

When I set the drop folder to (escaped network share path):

```
\\\\VSALM\\share\\$(Build.DefinitionName)\\$(Build.BuildNumber)
```

Then the build step succeeds but the files are not dropped under the path of the share.
They are dropped here in my case:

> C:\VSALM\share\MyBuildDefinition\20160723.7\drop

I don't know why it doesn't work with my share set to:

> C:\**workspaces**\share

but it works when I create a network share in

> C:\drop\share

and set the drop folder path in my build definition to:

```
\\\\drop\\share\\$(Build.DefinitionName)\\$(Build.BuildNumber)
```

**Question:**
Someone knows how to fix this script?

Comment: Does the shared folder exist on the build agent?

Comment: Yes, the shared folder is on the build agent.

Comment: and the shared folder is accessible.

Answer (score 1):

"Publish Build Artifacts" task publishes the build output to a shared network path when you select "File Share" type. The "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error usually occurs when the shared network path cannot be found. Please check if the "Path" you entered is correct and can be accessed from the build agent. The format is usually like following:

```
\\hostnameoripaddress\sharedfolder
```

When you enter a path with "\\\\" prefix, the task will copy the output to the root of the drive where the build agent located. For example, your build agent work folder is placed in C drive, when you specify "\\\\VSALM\share" as the path, it will copy files to "C:\VSALM\Share" folder(It will create the folder if the path does not exist).

Comment: You have just repeated the findings from my question above. I tried it this way `\\hostname\sharedFolder` but I get the mentioned error. The stack size exceeds because the recursive function has no end. The share is accessible. When I set a local path on the build agent like `C:\share`, it also does not work. I get the error: `File already exists`. It' definitely a bug I would say.

Comment: But with this hack, I can at least drop into a local folder ;-)

Comment: @Legends I didn't see any issue when I try with a shared network folder at my side. Can you try to set the shared network can be accessed by "Everyone" temporary to see if the task can be finished successfully?

Comment: @Legends If I enter an invalid network path, I will get the "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.

Comment: But if I enter a regular network path, this means a correctly formated one, not an escaped one, the I get the call stack size exceeded error. If I would enter a wrong or invalid network path, I would expect a message like "Path not found" :-). Btw, adding everyone under security of the share folder did the thing! But I don't like everyone to have access... So it was an authorization issue. In this case I would expect sth. like "Access denied" :-)

Comment: @Legends So, does your build agent running with network service account? Can you configure it to run with an account which has the access to the shared network path? https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/agents/windows#changewindowsserviceaccount

Comment: No, it runs under Local Service. The network path is a share on the Build Agent Server. I mean, I use the TFS2015 VM from MS. So everything is running on one machine (VM).

Comment: I changed the vsoAgent to run under the network service account.
When I go to AgentPools then the agent running in my custom pool is red.
Log file:
`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.AccessDeniedException: Access denied. NETWORK SERVICE needs Listen permissions for pool MyPool to perform the action`

Comment: Added network srvice to Agent pool Service accounts, now it works, thanks!

Comment: Actually it does not work yet, I get this error:
`Access to the path 'C:\workspaces\agent\_work\SourceRootMapping\25135ba2-f6a8-48bc-9aaa-16301526f7b4\2\SourceFolder.json' is denied` using the Network Service Acount.

Comment: @Legends This seems to be caused by the file is created by the old account, can you try creating a new definition to see if it can works?

Comment: Hu, I got several permission related issues now when using "Network service"! I had to give permissons to the agent folder and some subfolders explicitly because it didn't apply the settings i applied to the root folder recursively. The permissions where needed by the Copy files build step in order to access the Build Source Directory. 
Also for the build step "Index  Sources and Publish Symbols" I used a network share on the same machine, I had to explicitly give the "Network service" access.

But now it really works ;-)

Comment: And to make it clear, the "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error is permission related in my case...weird. Didn't know, that when using the network service account, I have to explicitly set the permissions for every folder on the same machine...

Comment: Old account? Ok, I thought TFS would apply the new account instantly...good to know that it doesn't!

Comment: An issue that also occured, was that the hosts entry for my website in IIS 
`127.0.0.1  testsite` was deleted somehow. Don't know if that is TFS related. But I didn't delete it.

Comment: The "\\\\" prefix tip saved my day! Thanks